# Yup: Como fazer uma regra condicional?

Tags: react, yup

Estou tentando fazer uma regra condicional com Yup, mas seguindo os passos da documentação, eu recebo esse erro:

> TypeError: ref must be a string, got: true if (typeof key !==
>   'string') throw new TypeError('ref must be a string, got: ' + key); |
>   ^ 17 | this.key = key.trim(); 18 | if (key === '') throw new
>   TypeError('ref must be a non-empty string'); 19 | this.isContext =
>   this.key[0] === prefixes.context;

Essa é minha definição de regras:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    login: Yup.string()
        .email('Email don't valid')
        .required('Fill the email!'),
    password: Yup.string().required('You need to fill the password').when(user.hasOwnProperty('id'), {
        is: false
    }),
})
```

Quero fazer uma regra condicional que quando meu objeto `user` não possuir a propriedade `id`, tornar o `password` `required`. Alguma ideia?

Comment: A resposta resolveu seu problema? Se sim, considere marcá-la como solução

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    login: Yup.string()
        .email('Email don"t valid')
        .required('Fill the email!'),
    password: Yup.string().when('userId', (user.hasOwnProperty('id'), field) =>
          user.hasOwnProperty('id') ? field.required() : field
    ),
})
```

Comment: Vou testar em breve e te dou um feedback